# Smallest irreducible periodic Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> What would be the smallest periodic Markov chain?

We're studying periodic Markov chains in my probability course. I'm just trying to picture the smallest possible one but I can't seem to come up with it.

Comment: What do you know?

Comment: We're studying periodic markov chains in my probability course. I'm just trying to picture the smallest possible one but I can't seem to come up with it. I'm not sure how to construct such a markov chain.

Comment: $0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to\ldots$

Comment: So the two states would be $0$ and $1$? What would be the probability of advancing to each state.

Comment: From state $0$ you go to state $1$ with probability $1$ and from state $1$ you go to state $0$ with probability $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to0\to1\to\ldots$ -- [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975518/smallest-irreducible-periodic-markov-chain#comment2000272_975518)

From state $0$ you go to state $1$ with probability $1$ and from state $1$ you go to state $0$ with probability $1$. -- [Ritz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975518/smallest-irreducible-periodic-markov-chain#comment2001407_975518)